# How to get various device information with WinJS

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

Concretely, I'd like to get the following information about the users device:

- <strike>A unique ID that identifies the users device, such as a Device-GUID or a Hardware-ID</strike>
- The device manufacturer and model name
- OS Buildstring or other information about the users OS patch level

What's possible and how can I get this data with WinJS?

**Edit**: I got the Hardware-ID. After some googling I finally wrapped my head around how to use [Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.getPackageSpecificToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx)

```
function getHardwareId() {
    var ht = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.getPackageSpecificToken(null);

    var reader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.fromBuffer(ht.id);
    var arr = new Array(ht.id.length);
    reader.readBytes(arr);

    var id = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        id += arr[j].toString();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft it is not possible in Windows Store apps.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dab68444-d609-48b8-9291-cbe152234fc7/get-device-manufacturermodel-information